How is possible migrate ASP.NET security (ApplicationSignInManager, ApplicationUserManager, AccountController, Microsoft.Owin.Security) to .NET 8?
In previous version Microsoft ASP.NET site automatically created individual user security with a number of special classes. And now any ASP.NET MVC sites has a lot of special controllers for manage users in databases with that special classes from namespaces
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPageBase.User

Now most of this packages marked as deprecated. What common Microsoft Idea to migrate site authentication with existing user databases from ASP.NET MVC to ASP.NET Core?
Is it possible to use existing code ASP.NET MVC code with existing database in ASP.NET Core 8 ?
What common idea?
Or idea is full rewriting existing site with new library Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect and other new library?

This may helps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/identity?view=aspnetcore-8.0
